# Clarification on sharing NTFS and installing GRUB2 with Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8, ntfs

I have a small amount of experience with installing Ubuntu (i.e. dual-booting on a Macbook and replacing Vista on an old HDD), but I am now planning on dual-booting my Asus laptop (currently running Windows 8.1) with 14.04, and I have gathered that it is an entirely different beast. So, I was hoping to get some clarification on a couple points that I have heard conflicting or incomplete information about in the past, before I make any rash decisions.

First, I understand that Windows and Ubuntu both support NTFS. Is it, then, logical to shrink the Windows partition by a fair margin and  make a relatively small root partition for Ubuntu, and then fill the rest of the space (excluding swap, etc.) with `/home` to share between both OSs, or would this cause problems or require additional steps that I am currently unaware of? Would it be better to have a small `/home` partition solely for Ubuntu and another large  NTFS one to share? And if so, how would I go about permanently mounting that to both operating systems so that they can be read and written to from either side, or is it somewhat automatic?

Second, I have heard from some that in order to avoid Windows overwriting GRUB, it should be installed on the Ubuntu partition. I have also heard that is is highly likely to cause problems and might not work at all. Is it easier to install the boot loader on the Windows partition and just keep the Live CD handy in case of disaster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid making `/home` a NTFS partition, it does not support file permissions which may cause some headaches later. Besides that, if you plan on using hibernation, it may also lead to file loss and data corruption when you boot into Ubuntu while Windows is hibernated (and vice versa).

If you really have a need to share files, create another partition. So your disk layout will be:

- Windows hidden boot partition.
- C: Windows OS & programs
- D: NTFS shared files
- Ubuntu root and `/home` partition (or separate them if you like to)
- swap partition (optional)

Since you have a Windows 8 installation, I guess that you have an EFI system where you need to install the GRUB image on a small "EFI system partition". I am not too familiar with this, so have a look at some related questions.